# build gdal3.2 encounter proj_api.h error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct projUV projUV’

Tags: gdal, proj

How do I fix this error when making GDAL 3.2.0 (have also tried 3.0.4, 3.1.0) from source.

The messages are:

```
In file included from /usr/include/projects.h:284:0,
                 from /usr/include/ogdi/ecs_util.h:110,
                 from /usr/include/ogdi/ecs.h:353,
                 from ogrogdi.h:40,
                 from ogrogdidriver.cpp:30:
/usr/include/proj_api.h:113:37: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct projUV projUV’
     typedef struct { double u, v; } projUV;
                                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/ogdi/ecs_util.h:110:0,
                 from /usr/include/ogdi/ecs.h:353,
                 from ogrogdi.h:40,
                 from ogrogdidriver.cpp:30:
/usr/include/projects.h:147:33: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct projUV projUV’
 typedef struct { double u, v; } projUV;
                                 ^
../../../GDALmake.opt:646: recipe for target '../o/ogrogdidriver.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [../o/ogrogdidriver.lo] Error 1
```

===================
My configuration by

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-proj=/usr --with-python=python3 CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/proj/include -DACCEPT_USE_OF_DEPRECATED_PROJ_API_H" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib"
```

```
GDAL is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Installation directory:    /usr
  C compiler:                gcc -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2
  C++ compiler:              g++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2
  C++14 support:             no

  LIBTOOL support:           yes

  LIBZ support:              external
  libdeflate support:        no
  LIBLZMA support:           no
  ZSTD support:              no
  cryptopp support:          no
  crypto/openssl support:    yes
  GRASS support:             no
  CFITSIO support:           no
  PCRaster support:          internal
  LIBPNG support:            external
  DDS support:               no
  GTA support:               no
  LIBTIFF support:           external (BigTIFF=yes)
  LIBGEOTIFF support:        internal
  LIBJPEG support:           external
  12 bit JPEG:               no
  12 bit JPEG-in-TIFF:       no
  LIBGIF support:            external
  JPEG-Lossless/CharLS:      no
  OGDI support:              yes
  HDF4 support:              yes
  HDF5 support:              yes
  Kea support:               no
  NetCDF support:            yes
  NetCDF has netcdf_mem.h:   no
  Kakadu support:            no
  JasPer support:            yes (GeoJP2=yes)
  OpenJPEG support:          yes
  ECW support:               no
  MrSID support:             no
  MrSID/MG4 Lidar support:   no
  JP2Lura support:           no
  MSG support:               no
  EPSILON support:           no
  WebP support:              yes
  cURL support (wms/wcs/...):yes
  PostgreSQL support:        yes
  LERC support:              yes
  MySQL support:             no
  Ingres support:            no
  Xerces-C support:          yes
  Expat support:             yes
  libxml2 support:           yes
  Google libkml support:     yes
  ODBC support:              yes
  FGDB support:              no
  MDB support:               no
  PCIDSK support:            internal
  OCI support:               no
  GEORASTER support:         no
  Rasdaman support:          no
  RDB support:               no
  DODS support:              no
  SQLite support:            yes
  PCRE support:              yes
  SpatiaLite support:        no
  RasterLite2 support:       no
  Teigha (DWG and DGNv8):    no
  INFORMIX DataBlade support:no
  GEOS support:              yes
  SFCGAL support:            no
  QHull support:             external
  Poppler support:           no
  Podofo support:            no
  PDFium support:            no
  OpenCL support:            no
  Armadillo support:         no
  FreeXL support:            yes
  SOSI support:              no
  MongoDB support:           no
  MongoCXX v3 support:       no
  HDFS support:              no
  TileDB support:            no
  EXR support:               yes
  HEIF support:              no
  userfaultfd support:       yes
  misc. gdal formats:        aaigrid adrg aigrid airsar arg blx bmp bsb cals ceos ceos2 coasp cosar ctg dimap dted e00grid elas envisat ers esric fit gff gsg gxf hf2 idrisi ignfheightasciigrid ilwis ingr iris iso8211 jaxapalsar jdem kmlsuperoverlay l1b leveller map mrf msgn ngsgeoid nitf northwood pds prf r raw rmf rs2 safe saga sdts sentinel2 sgi sigdem srtmhgt terragen tga til tsx usgsdem xpm xyz zmap rik ozi eeda plmosaic rda wcs wms wmts daas ogcapi rasterlite mbtiles grib pdf
  disabled gdal formats:    
  misc. ogr formats:         aeronavfaa arcgen avc bna cad csv dgn dxf edigeo flatgeobuf geoconcept georss gml gmt gpsbabel gpx gtm htf jml mapml mvt ntf openair openfilegdb pgdump rec s57 segukooa segy selafin shape sua svg sxf tiger vdv wasp xplane idrisi pds sdts amigocloud carto cloudant couchdb csw elastic ngw plscenes wfs gpkg vfk osm nas ili gmlas ods xlsx lvbag odbc pgeo mssqlspatial geomedia walk
  disabled ogr formats:     


  SWIG Bindings:             python 

  PROJ >= 6:                 yes
  enable GNM building:       yes
  enable pthread support:    yes
  enable POSIX iconv support:yes
  hide internal symbols:     no
```

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS, and PROJ version 7.2.0 (have tried 6.3.2), GEOS version is 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

After reading a 2012 mailing list, I got it done by
#ifndef PROJECTS_H
typedef struct { double u, v; } projUV;
#endif
in proj_api.h..

Now gdal 3.2 built ok
ref: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/proj/2012-April/005842.html